# site download with svg animation

Tags: svg, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to clone the following URL and translate it to my language:
`http://interactive.unwomen.org/multimedia/infographic/violenceagainstwomen/en/index.html`
unfortunately, the site has some SVG animations that make downloading hard. I tied `wget` and `WebHTTrack`. both of them download all files but SVG illustrations.
any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If You just need the final SVG (after animations are finished) here they are: https://jsfiddle.net/3bt4th0d/

Comment: thanks. I replaced `svg` in my index.html with code that you have been shared. now I have the first page illustrations but none of the links are working now.